# I need a query to get the output from the given table

Tags: sql, oracle

Table Position as below.

```
CREATE TABLE position (
tran_Date date,
clientid varchar(255),
stock varchar(255),
quantity number
);

insert into position values ('23-AUG-2018','Client1','Infosys',100);
insert into position values ('23-AUG-2018','Client1','Wipro',200);
insert into position values ('23-AUG-2018','Client1','TechM',150);
insert into position values ('23-AUG-2018','Client2','IBM',100);
insert into position values ('24-AUG-2018','Client1','Infosys',150);
insert into position values ('24-AUG-2018','Client1','Wipro',150);
insert into position values ('24-AUG-2018','Client2','IBM',100);
```

**I need a query to get the data from position table as below format. The answer should be a single query.**

```
ClientID, 
Stock, 
ChangeInQty(a calculative bucket which will hold the diff of qty between 2 dates),
classification(a calculative bucket on changeinqty. 
    IF changeinqty in '-'(negative) 'shares taken down'
    if changeinqty in '+'(positive) 'shares taken up'
    if changeinqty in '0'(no change) 'shares remain same'
    if changeinqty is indeterminable 'shares position removed')
```

My approach was this.

```
Select clientid,stock,changeinqty, 
case 
when x.changeinqty >0 then 'Taken Up'
when x.changeinqty <0 then 'Taken Down'
when x.changeinqty =0 then 'Same'
when x.changeinqty is null then 'Removed'
end as classification
From (select a.clientid,a.stock,a.quantity-b.quantity as changeinqty from
(Select tran_date,clientid,stock,quantity from position where tran_date='23-Aug-2018')  a left join
(Select tran_date,clientid,stock,quantity from position where tran_date='24-Aug-2018')  b
on a.clientid=b.clientid and a.stock=b.stock) x;
```

Comment: Tip: clientid should be an integer column, no need to store long varchar values over and over again.

Comment: You should post what you have tried and what issues you are running into. StackOverflow's community of contributors are here the **help**, but not write your code for you. Here's a good post explaining this: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977

Comment: Which should be the date to calculating ? What is the qty column ? what kind of calculative bucket on classification? Please elaborate properly.

Comment: these If conditions can be achieved from Decode in oracle. https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php . please research on this and post some of your research.

Comment: Select clientid,stock,changeinqty, 
case 
when x.changeinqty >0 then 'Taken Up'
when x.changeinqty <0 then 'Taken Down'
when x.changeinqty =0 then 'Same'
when x.changeinqty is null then 'Removed'
end as classification
From (select a.clientid,a.stock,a.quantity-b.quantity as changeinqty from
(Select tran_date,clientid,stock,quantity from position where tran_date='23-Aug-2018')  a left join
(Select tran_date,clientid,stock,quantity from position where tran_date='24-Aug-2018')  b
on a.clientid=b.clientid and a.stock=b.stock) x;


I have done that. And it's working fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site where you can ask questions and get answers about problems you're having with software you've written, but it is not a "do my homework for me" or "do my job for me" site. When you ask a question you should include the code you've written and the specific errors you're getting or the results your program produces and an explanation of the results you expected. Without that there's really not much we can do to help you. Please edit your question to show what you've done and tell us what problems the code has. Again, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Any better approach anyone else can suggest?

Comment: I don't think the close votes are appropriate.  The OP has fixed the question as requested.

Answer (score 2):

Here is alternative way to find

```
select clientid,
stock, 
quantity,
a.change_stock,
case when a.change_stock < 0 THEN  'shares taken down' 
when a.change_stock > 0 THEN  'shares taken up'
when a.change_stock = 0 THEN  'shares remain same' end classification from (
Select clientid,stock, quantity,  lead(quantity,1,0) over ( partition by clientid,stock order by tran_Date asc) - quantity change_stock 
from position ) a
where a.quantity + a.change_stock <> 0
union all
select clientid, -- query to take non-duplicate row
stock, 
quantity,null,'shares position removed' from (select clientid,
stock, 
quantity , count(*) over (partition by clientid,stock) cnt from position )a where a.cnt=1;
```

Here is combined query with takes care of duplicate and non-duplicates without union all

```
select clientid,
stock, 
quantity,
case when a.cnt=1 THEN NULL ELSE a.change_stock END change_stock,
case when a.change_stock < 0 and a.cnt > 1 THEN  'shares taken down' 
when a.change_stock > 0 and a.cnt > 1 THEN  'shares taken up'
when a.change_stock = 0 and a.cnt > 1 THEN  'shares remain same' 
when a.cnt=1 THEN 'shares position removed' end classification from (
Select clientid,stock, quantity,  lead(quantity,1,0) over ( partition by clientid,stock order by tran_Date asc) - quantity change_stock ,count(*) over (partition by clientid,stock) cnt
from position ) a
where a.quantity + a.change_stock <> 0 or cnt=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks okay, but I would simplify it to:

```
Select p1.clientid, p1.stock, (p2.quantity - p1.quantity) as changeinqty, 
       (case when p2.quantity is null then 'Removed'
             when p2.quantity > p1.quantity then 'Taken Up'
             when p2.quantity < p1.quantity then 'Taken Down'
             when p2.quantity = p1.quantity then 'Same'
        end) as classification
From position p1 left join
     position p2
     on p1.client_id = p2.client_id and
        p1.stock = p2.stock and
        p2.tran_date = date '2018-08-24'
where p1.tran_date = date '2018-08-23;
```

Notes:

- The condition for the first date is in the `where` clause so these are the only positions considered.
- The condition for the second date is in the `on` clause so all rows from the first date are included, even those that are missing.
- I think the logic for your code is backwards.  This is more transparent.
- Oracle supports the `date` keyword, so you can use ISO/ANSI standard formats for dates.

Answer (score 1):

I would condense it to something like this:

```
select day1.clientid
     , day1.stock
     , day1.quantity - day2.quantity as changeinqty
     , case sign(day1.quantity - day2.quantity)
           when 1 then 'Up'
           when -1 then 'Down'
           when 0 then 'Unchanged'
           else 'Removed'
       end as classification
from   demo_position day1
       left join demo_position day2
            on  day2.clientid = day1.clientid
            and day2.stock = day1.stock
            and day2.tran_date = day1.tran_date +1
where  day1.tran_date = date '2018-08-23';
```

I'm guessing (perhaps wrongly) that the report compares one day with the next, so I've replaced the later hardcoded date with `day1.tran_date +1`.

(Just seen Gordon's answer which is along the same lines. As he mentions in his answer, it looks as though `day1.quantity - day2.quantity` should actually be `day2.quantity - day1.quantity` to match the Up/Down/Unchanged labels. I changed the labels while I was at it, because [takedown](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/takedown) and [takeup](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/take-up) didn't seem to be what you meant.)

Answer (score 1):

You include hard coded dates in your script. This works for your sample data but will fail if there are any gaps in dates. The following script scans previous positions and compares the current row's position with the last position. This should work for any data, and any date:

```
select *, (p.quantity - prevP.quantity) as change
from dbo.position p
left outer join dbo.position prevP
on p.clientid = prevP.clientid
    and p.stock = prevP.stock
    and prevP.tran_Date = (select max(allPrevP.tran_Date)
                            from dbo.position allPrevP
                            where allPrevP.clientid = prevP.clientid
                                and allPrevP.stock = p.stock
                                and allPrevP.tran_Date < p.tran_Date
                            group by allPrevP.clientid, allPrevP.stock)
order by p.clientid, p.stock, p.tran_Date
```

Comment: Although my solution should work, kanagaraj's use of partition and LEAD() is much more elegant.